# Enabling Components on JFrame from JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

1. I have an JFrame on which there is JMenubar which has several JMenu and JMenuItem.
   I have set allJMenu.setVisible(false) and allJMenuItem.setVisible(false) and  called JInternalFrame(Login Form)
2. JInternalFrame(Login Form) if the username and password are correct than i have to set visiblity true for appropriate JMenu and JMenuItem depending upon type of login(admin,user etc.)
3. How should i achieve this?

I tried   it in two ways
**First Way:**

```
 public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame 
      {
         public LoginForm() 
        {
           initComponents();
        }

            my code......

        if(username==correct && password==correct)
        {
             //how should i set the JMenu and JMenuItem as visible=true
             //i tried the below code but does not works

           Main_JFrame  mi = new Main_JFrame();
           mi.allJMenu.setVisible(true);
           mi.allJMenuItem.setVisible(true);            //doesn't works
```

**Second Way:**

```
           Main_JFrame  mi1=new Main_JFrame(); 
           mi1.visibleTrue(mi1.MenuItem1);          
           mi1.visibleTrue(mi1.Menu5);            //doesn't works
        }
      }
```

**visibleTrue** is a method in JFrame Form(Main_JFrame).The method is as below:

```
     public void visibleTrue(Component cmp)
    {
       cmp.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need to setVisible(false) for all MenuItems that are added under JMenu.
Setting JMenu.setVisible(false) is enough. 
 You need to process all items in menuBar and call setVisible(true) on them, like this

```
    private static void setComponentsEnable(final JComponent component, final boolean enabled) {
        final Component[] vComponents = component instanceof  JMenu ? ((JMenu)component).getMenuComponents() : component.getComponents();
        for (final Component vComponent : vComponents) {
            if (vComponent instanceof JMenu)
                setComponentsEnable((JMenu)vComponent, true);
            vComponent.setVisible(enabled);
        }
    }
```

and here is a small demo

```
public class EnableComp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some Title");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        final JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("menu1");
        final JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("item1");
        item1.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menu1.add(item1);
        menu1.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        final JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("menu2");
        final JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("item2");
        item2.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menu2.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menu2.add(item2);
        menuBar.add(menu2);

        final JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("I m added directly in menuBar");
        item3.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menuBar.add(item3);

        final JButton tempBtn = new JButton("i m simple btn in menuBar");
        tempBtn.setVisible(false);//visible false
        menuBar.add(tempBtn);

        panel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JButton enableBtn = new JButton("Show Menu");
        enableBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                setComponentsEnable(menuBar, true);
            }
        });

        panel.add(enableBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static void setComponentsEnable(final JComponent component, final boolean enabled) {
        final Component[] vComponents = component instanceof  JMenu ? ((JMenu)component).getMenuComponents() : component.getComponents();
        for (final Component vComponent : vComponents) {
            if (vComponent instanceof JMenu)
                setComponentsEnable((JMenu)vComponent, true);
            vComponent.setVisible(enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaces my **visibleTrue()** with your **setComponentsEnable(component,boolean)** but its not working

Comment: Are you passing JMenuBar to **setComponentsEnable(component,boolean)** ? If yes and your  JMenuBar contians JPanel then you need to use `instanceOf` test in **setComponentsEnable(component,boolean)** and call **setComponentsEnable(component,boolean)** recursively

Comment: no i have passed JMenu **mi.setComponentsEnable(mi.Menu1,true);**

Comment: for JMenu we need to call **((JMenu)component).getMenuComponents()**, i updated my code

Comment: You can copy the class **EnableComp** pasted above and see by yourself that code works(you need to import java classes).

Comment: I think i am not able to access JFrame components from JInternalFrame